# How to hide a text widget and show it later in tcl tk?

Tags: widget, tcl, hide, tk-toolkit

I have a problem with my display of multiple choice questions. I have a frame which shows the questions and choices above a text widget which shows if the chosen answer is correct. Yet I want to hide the text while the test is not finished.
It looks like that:
[image]

My procedures are following:

```
proc beginTest { number } {

    startTest

    .frq.txt configure -state normal
    .frq.txt delete 1.0 end
    set score 0
    set save 0

    set path Files/Tutorials/$::Tuto
    set numbers { 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 }
    for {set i 1} {$i<=10} {incr i} {
        if { $::stop == 1 } {
            set answer [tk_dialog .dialog "Quit test?" "If you quit the test now, your answers will be lost. Do you want to continue?" \
            question 1 "Continue test" "Quit test"]
            if {$answer == 0} {
                continue
            } else {
                break
            }
        } else {
            set ind [expr {int(rand()*[llength $numbers])} ]
            incr score [displayQuestion $path [lindex $numbers $ind] $i 10]
            set numbers [lreplace $numbers $ind $ind]
        }
    }

    .frq.txt insert end "Your score: $score/10"
    .frq.txt configure -state disabled
    if {[info exist user]} {
        if {[lindex $::testScores $number]== "Not Taken" || [lindex $::testScores $number] < $score} {
            set ::testScores [lreplace $::testScores $number $number $score]
        }
    }

    destroy .frq.fr2
}
```

The following procedure called at the first line of the previous one create and define the windows, frames, text zone, etc.

```
proc startTest {} {
    destroy .fr

    #window definition
    toplevel .frq
    wm title .frq "Test" 
    wm geometry .frq 740x670+0+0
    .frq configure -bg $::bgColour

    # title of section
    label .frq.titl
    .frq.titl configure -font "arial 20" -pady 10
    grid .frq.titl -column 0 -row 0 -sticky swe
    .frq.titl configure -background "White"

    # define the main text zone
    text .frq.txt -wrap word -yscroll {.frq.vscroll set} -highlightthickness 0
    .frq.txt configure -background "White" ;#"slate gray" to debug
    scrollbar .frq.vscroll -orient vertical -command {.frq.txt yview}
    grid .frq.txt -column 0 -row 1 -sticky snwe
    grid rowconfigure .frq 1 -weight 1
    grid columnconfigure .frq 0 -weight 1
    grid .frq.vscroll -column 1 -row 1 -sticky snwe
    .frq.txt tag configure center -justify center
    .frq.txt configure -font "times 12" -state disabled
    .frq.vscroll configure -orient vertical -command {.frq.txt yview}
    grid .frq.txt -column 0 -row 1 -sticky snwe
    .frq.txt configure -state normal
    .frq.txt delete 1.0 end

    #text styles
    .frq.txt tag configure Normal -font "times 12"
    .frq.txt tag configure subTitle -font "times 14"
    .frq.txt tag configure Titlec -font "times 16" -justify "center"
    .frq.txt tag configure subTitlec -font "times 14" -justify "center"
    .frq.txt tag configure subTitlecu -font "times 14"  -justify "center" -underline on
    .frq.txt tag configure Titlecu -font "times 16" -justify "center" -underline on
    .frq.txt tag configure Title -font "times 16"
    .frq.txt tag configure link -foreground blue -font "times 12"
    .frq.txt tag configure right -foreground "forest green"
    .frq.txt tag configure wrong -foreground red
    .frq.txt tag configure enhance -background "light goldenrod"
    .frq.txt tag configure rightenhance -background "light goldenrod" -foreground "forest green"
    .frq.txt tag bind link <Enter> ".fr.txt configure -cursor hand1"
    .frq.txt tag bind link <Leave> ".fr.txt configure -cursor arrow"

    #questions frame 
    frame .frq.fr2 -background white
    grid .frq.fr2 -row 1

    label .frq.lbl -relief flat -font arial -text "Question 1 of 5"
    grid .frq.lbl -row 0
    text .frq.fr2.txt -relief flat -background white -font "times 13" -wrap word
    grid .frq.fr2.txt -columnspan 2 -row 1
    .frq.fr2.txt tag configure center -justify center
    grid rowconfigure .frq 1 -weight 1

    checkbutton .frq.fr2.cb1 -command "choose A" -cursor hand1
    grid .frq.fr2.cb1 -column 0 -row 2
    label .frq.fr2.lblA -background white -font "arial 12" -pady 3
    bind .frq.fr2.lblA <ButtonRelease> "choose A; .frq.fr2.cb1 toggle"
    grid .frq.fr2.lblA -column 1 -row 2 -sticky w
    checkbutton .frq.fr2.cb2 -command "choose B" -cursor hand1
    grid .frq.fr2.cb2 -column 0 -row 3
    label .frq.fr2.lblB -background white -font "arial 12" -pady 3
    bind .frq.fr2.lblB <ButtonRelease> "choose B; .frq.fr2.cb2 toggle"
    grid .frq.fr2.lblB -column 1 -row 3 -sticky w
    checkbutton .frq.fr2.cb3 -command "choose C" -cursor hand1
    grid .frq.fr2.cb3 -column 0 -row 4
    label .frq.fr2.lblC -background white -font "arial 12" -pady 3
    bind .frq.fr2.lblC <ButtonRelease> "choose C; .frq.fr2.cb3 toggle"
    grid .frq.fr2.lblC -column 1 -row 4 -sticky w
    checkbutton .frq.fr2.cb4 -command "choose D" -cursor hand1
    grid .frq.fr2.cb4 -column 0 -row 5
    label .frq.fr2.lblD -background white -font "arial 12" -pady 3
    bind .frq.fr2.lblD <ButtonRelease> "choose D; .frq.fr2.cb4 toggle"
    grid .frq.fr2.lblD -column 1 -row 5 -sticky w

    frame .frq.bar
    grid .frq.bar -row 2
    button .frq.bar.next -text "Next question >>" -state disabled -pady 5 -borderwidth 0 -command "set ::goOn 1"
    pack .frq.bar.next -padx 5 -pady 5 -side right -fill none
    button .frq.bar.dp -text "Open drawing pad" -pady 5 -borderwidth 0 -command notepad
    pack .frq.bar.dp -padx 5 -pady 5 -side right -fill none
    button .frq.bar.calc -text "Open calculator" -pady 5 -borderwidth 0 -command calculator
    pack .frq.bar.calc -padx 5 -pady 5 -side right -fill none
    button .frq.bar.quit -text "Quit test" -pady 5 -borderwidth 0 -command "set ::stop 1; set ::goOn 1"
    pack .frq.bar.quit -padx 5 -pady 5 -side right -fill none
}
```

And finally, the procedure which display the question:

```
proc displayQuestion {path filename ind maxind} {

    set fd [open $path/$filename r]
    set questionFile [split [read $fd] "\n"]
    set ::goOn 0
    set answers [list]
    set imgFlag 0
    set fd [open $path/answers/$filename r]
    set goodAnswer [read $fd]
    close $fd
    .frq.lbl configure -text "Question $ind of $maxind"
    .frq.fr2.txt configure -state normal
    .frq.fr2.txt delete 1.0 end
    .frq.fr2.txt insert end \n

    foreach line $questionFile {
        if {$line == "<image>"} {
            set imgFlag 1
            continue
        } 
        if {$imgFlag == 1} {
            set imgFlag 0
            .frq.fr2.txt insert end " " center
            .frq.fr2.txt image create end -image [image create photo -file [file join "$path/$line"]]
            continue
        }
        if {[string match A)* $line]} {
            .frq.fr2.lblA configure -text $line
            lappend answers $line
            continue
        }
        if {[string match B)* $line]} {
            .frq.fr2.lblB configure -text $line
            lappend answers $line
            continue
        }
        if {[string match C)* $line]} {
            .frq.fr2.lblC configure -text $line
            lappend answers $line
            continue
        }
        if {[string match D)* $line]} {
            .frq.fr2.lblD configure -text $line
            lappend answers $line
            continue
        }
        .frq.fr2.txt insert end $line\n center
    }

    .frq.fr2.txt configure -state disabled
    .frq.txt insert end [lindex $questionFile 0]\n
    .frq.fr2.cb1 deselect
    .frq.fr2.cb2 deselect
    .frq.fr2.cb3 deselect
    .frq.fr2.cb4 deselect
    .frq.bar.next configure -state disabled
    set ::choice 0
    vwait ::goOn

    switch $::choice {
        A { set ind 0 }
        B { set ind 1 }
        C { set ind 2 }
        default { set ind 3 }
    }

     if { $::choice == $goodAnswer} {
        .frq.txt insert end "Correct answer: [lindex $answers $ind]\n\n" right
        return 1
    } else {
        switch $goodAnswer {
            A { set i 0 }
            B { set i 1 }
            C { set i 2 }
            default { set i 3 }
        }
        .frq.txt insert end "Wrong answer: [lindex $answers $ind]\n\tYou should have pick [lindex $answers $i]\n\n" wrong
        return 0
    }
}
```

The widget concerned is ".frq.txt".
I have tried "pack" and "pack forget", even tried a way to use the option "-elide" but I am out of ideas.
Could you help me?

Comment: My thought would be to change the font color to be the same as the background color of the text widget.    Why doesn't pack forget work?

Comment: Probably because it isn't packed in the first place, but gridded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `grid` to manage the contents of the `.frq` widget, including the `.frq.txt` widget, you need to use `grid remove` or `grid forget` to make the widget vanish. The difference between the two? With `grid remove`, the sizing metadata for the cell is remembered.

`pack forget` is for undoing a `pack` (strictly, a `pack configure`, though the simple `pack` pretends you said `pack configure`).

Comment: I understand, will a 'grid remove' or 'grid forget' able me to show it later?

Comment: Effectively, `grid remove`"hide my text, but when the test is over, I cannot have it back. And I need it.

Comment: Ok, I just add `grid .frq.txt`after my test according to the "grid manual" and all works as I wanted to. Thanks.

Comment: The difference is that when you `grid` the widget back in, if it was `grid remove` then it goes back where it was, and if you `grid forget` it goes in wherever new widgets get added.